# How to check if thread execution is completed or not

Tags: c#, .net

I am executing a thread which invokes BCP out in command prompt using C# win apps.
I want to do some action if thread execution is completed i.e. BCP out is completed.
BCP out is carried on local machine.
How should i check whether the thread execution is completed or not ???
my code looks like

```
using(this.proc = new Process())
{
    var procStartInfo = 
    new ProcessStartInfo(cmdFileName)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

    this.proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    if(this.proc.Start())
    {
        var thread1 = new Thread(this.GetError)  { IsBackground = true };
        var thread2 = new Thread(this.GetOutput) { IsBackground = true };
        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();

        // check if thread execution is completed then do some logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to wait for the Threads or for the Process?

Comment: Process. as when BCp out is finished then only i have to move towards the next step. But to support process i have implemented 2 threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard trick is:

```
thread1.Join();
thread2.Join();

//can only get here once both threads are finished.
```

**Update**

Okay so you actually want to check if the process has exited?

Then you have the [HasExited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) property of `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Here's a slightly dirty way:

```
while(!proc.HasExited){
  Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait a second
}
```

Comment: thread1 checks for the error and thread2 checks for the output. code given by you will execute till completion of thread1 and during execution of thread2 if errors comes then error will not be read by thread1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Thread.IsAlive` property.

Another possibility is to use a AutoResetEvent the thread sets when it is finished. The calling thread can wait for several AutoResetEvents to be set. When all are set, all work is done.

Comment: does Thread.IsAlive property gets assigned to false when execution finishes or it's value is assigned to false only when the thread is aborted.

Comment: The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) says: true if this thread has been started and has not terminated normally or aborted; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 0):

With the `Process` class you can handle events like `Exited` by setting `EnableRaisingEvents` property to `true`, though this has some cost involved in terms of performance.

```
var p = new Process();
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);

public void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //handle exiting of process here.
}
```

Comment: actually i'm creating 2 threads for Getting the stdError and stdOutput which too is affecting performance. Is above way of doing it will improve performance instead of my implementation ?

Comment: I cannot say anything about performance, but it will tell you when your spwaned process exists.